# How can i read image from cell using xlsx-populate package

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, xlsx-populate

I am using `xlsx-populate` package to read the XLSX data using below code.

```js
// ... import statement reading file statement

wb.sheet(0).usedRange().forEach((cell: any) => {
    console.log(cell);
});
```

Instead of printing image data, It is printing the `undefined`. Here is my xlsx file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IxWwGoiFvTEKpU7QftK-yHEN6g_bMAXs/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114862659237247838905&rtpof=true&sd=true